# unable to compress image in flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

it is working for android but not in iOS following is the code
getting error "FileSystemExcetption: Cannot open file, path = "filepathg""  (OS error: !s a directory error=21)

Future<String?> savePdfFile() async {
Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

```
String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;

String id = DateTime.now().toString();

File file = File("$documentPath/$id.pdf");

file.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());

setState(() {
  pdf = pw.Document();
});

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  if (file.path.isNotEmpty) {
    String outputPath = await getTempPath();
    try {
      await PdfCompressor.compressPdfFile(
          file.path, outputPath, CompressQuality.MEDIUM);
      return outputPath;
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Unable to upload file please try again..!!';
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} else {
  if (file.path.isNotEmpty) {
    return file.path;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

}